# Does 'tuned' need to keep running?

Tags: centos, performance-tuning

On my CentOS 7 systems, I use `tuned-adm` to set a profile appropriate to the environment during configuration, but after that, I never subsequently change that profile. It seems that the *tuned* system spawns a process (`/usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P`) for dynamic monitoring and adjustment.  This process uses noticeably more memory compared to other daemons on my system.  I would like to reduce nonessential services on a certain memory-constrained server.  If I do not use a profile that involves dynamically adjusting parameters such as power consumption, does the `tuned` process need to keep running? Can I safely stop the process and have the profile that I originally set up persist from that point on?

Answer (score 2):

Tuned sets the performance optimizations at boot time. If you disable the process and reboot your server, optimizations would be lost.

You can; however, stop the process after boot and keep whatever settings tuned created at boot time. At least, this is what my testing showed.

Comment: I tried turning off the `tuned` service (`systemctl stop tuned`) and then checking the system parameters (via `sysctl`), but in my testing, turning off the daemon reverted the settings back to the values before `tuned` was running. I am curious why this is different from your environment. Can you explain how you did your testing?

Answer (score 2):

As of CentOS 7.2 `tuned` now has a no-daemon mode which can be turned on by setting `daemon = 0` in `/etc/tuned/tuned-main.conf`.  This is mentioned in the RedHat [Performance Tuning Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/performance_tuning_guide/index#ch-Tuned-overview).